# What's the command to get Mysql's total disk space?

Tags: mysql

Tried to do some researching and always ends up with

```
select concat(round(sum(DATA_LENGTH/1024/1024),2),'MB') as data 
    FROM TABLES WHERE table_schema='home';
```

which shows the total size that has already been used, is there any command that I can use to see the total disk space(capacity of the server)?

Comment: Do you mean the total disk space used by MySQL? Everything? Or just the tables? Do you have shell access to the server MySQL is on?

Comment: @Schwern I do have shell access to the server, and i mean the total disk space available for mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total disk space available to MySQL is the total space remaining on that disk partition. You can check that with the [`df` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Df_%28Unix%29). The MySQL database is often in `/var/lib/db` but you'll have to check your configuration to be sure.

If you're on a hosted server, you might also have a disk quota. How to check that depends on your hosting service.

Answer (score 6):

This question has been answered [around four years ago][1].

To sum up the answer, run this command:

```
mysql> select table_schema, sum((data_length+index_length)/1024/1024) AS MB from information_schema.tables group by 1;
+--------------------+-----------------+
| table_schema       | MB              |
+--------------------+-----------------+
| prod               | 298025.72448921 |
| information_schema |      0.00781248 |
| maatkit            |     70.77330779 |
| mysql              |      0.66873168 |
| test               |   4752.31449127 |
+--------------------+-----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

> If you have a very large number of tables, it can be slow, as you have
>   already discovered.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: it is the same code as what I found(as in my question), `select concat(round(sum((DATA_LENGTH+INDEX_LENGTH)/1024/1024),2),'MB') as data FROM TABLES;`, which shows how much has been used, not total that's available. ty anyways!